# Unescaping javascript string in Python

Tags: python

How would I decode the following string into normal text from javascript:

```
s = 'https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/normal-example\/ft_43513_53175ec44096a.mov'
```

I am currently doing `s.replace('\/','/')`, but there must be a better way?

Comment: Is that *exactly* how you're getting it from JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

You want to use decode with 'string-escape':

```
In [1]: s = 'https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/normal-example\/ft_43513_53175ec44096a.mov'.replace('\/', '/')

In [2]: s.decode('string-escape')
Out[2]: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/normal-example/ft_43513_53175ec44096a.mov'
```

The official docs on str.decode [are here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings).

The relevant portion is the [The purpose of string-escape is to] produce a string that is suitable as string literal in Python source code.